# python: scatter does not display

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have some trouble using scatter in python. I have 2 vectors of size 100 of latitudes and longitudes, and a vector 100 of corresponding data of values between 1 and 2.

I am trying to display these data on a north polar stereographic projected map, but nothing appears on the figure. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mpl_colors
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

lon=np.linspace(-180,180,num=100)


lat=np.linspace(75,75,num=100)
data=1+np.random.rand(100)

cmap  =  plt.cm.jet
norm_color = mpl_colors.Normalize(vmin=None, vmax=None, clip=False)
fig=plt.figure()
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=65,lon_0=310,resolution='l')
x,y = m(lon,lat)
m.scatter(x, y,marker='+',c=data,cmap=cmap, norm=norm_color,edgecolor='none') 
plt.show()
```

When I just scatter the coordinates: `m.scatter(x, y,marker='+')` it works fine (I have "+" at the corresponding coordinates, i.e on the 75° latitude projected circle). But when I want to add the data, nothing is displayed.

Where am I not using scatter right ?

Comment: The code works fine for me. What versions of numpy, matplotlib, and basemap are you using? And I guess the code that works should be `m.scatter(x, y,marker='+')`, not `m.scatter(xx, yy,marker='+')`

Comment: @dan-man I read the doc, thank you but I dont see how my code is wrong wrt the doc...

Comment: @FabianRost numpy 1.6.2, matplotlib 1.1.1rc2, basemap 1.0.3, and correct about the code thank you =)

Comment: I have numpy 1.10.2, matplotlib 1.5.1 and basemap 1.07. Your versions seem quite old. Can you upgrade?

Comment: I cannot, but it was not the problem. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem.

It is the simultaneous use of the options `marker='+'` and `edgecolor='None'`.

The latter allows to change the color of the edge of the marker. With the marker '+', the edge is the marker itself: that is why it was not displayed.

In replacement of the line `m.scatter(x, y,marker='+',c=data,cmap=cmap, norm=norm_color,edgecolor='none')` the following work:

```
m.scatter(x, y,marker='+',c=data,cmap=cmap, norm=norm_color)
```

or

```
m.scatter(x, y,marker='o',c=data,cmap=cmap, norm=norm_color,edgecolor='none')
```